# Can't find description for 'date' command in info bash - find a list of all commands callable from the shell

Tags: linux, macos, bash, shell, info

I'll mention this first - the goal of this question is really to bolster my understanding of bash and the `info bash` pages rather than to get specific answers on the functionality of the date command.

I'm unable to find *any* mention of the `date` command from the following indices of the `info bash` manual:

- Builtin Index::               Index of Bash builtin commands.
- Reserved Word Index::         Index of Bash reserved words.
- Variable Index::              Quick reference helps you find the
                              variable you want.
- Function Index::              Index of bindable Readline functions.

However, I'm able to get information on the date function with `info date`. This page seems to a part of the BSD General Commands Manual but I'm unable to find the index page of this manual - if I go to the containing node though typing 'u' this takes me to the 'dir' page rather than an general command index as I would expect.

My main concern here is that if I can't find information on the `date` command within `info bash`, then what other commands aren't listed within `info bash`? Is there a comprehensive list of all of the commands I can use within Bash?

Comment: What about the manpages (i.e. `man date`)?

Comment: I'm able to find information through `man date`, but I'm really trying to understand why there's no mention of `date` within `info bash`. As in, is `date` not a bash command, and a command inherited from elsewhere?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because finding docs is not programming.

Comment: `date` is no builtin command of bash. See: `type date` To see bash's builtin commands: `help`.

Comment: anyone have any advice on where to ask this question then?

Comment: I think that @Cyrus has already answered your question.

Comment: @Cyrus This does answer my question. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`info bash` and `man bash` only document Bash's *own* features.

***External utilities* such as `date` have nothing to with Bash per se**, even though you can *call* them from Bash.

- For any given *external utility* you'll find documentation in its specific `man` and `info` pages (if installed), as you've discovered.
- What muddles the issue is that **Bash has so-called *builtins* that look and behave like external utilities in many respects** - those have specific help topics that you can **invoke with `help`**; e.g., `help read`, but you can also find them **in `man bash` under the heading `SHELL BUILTIN COMMANDS`**.
  Furthermore, some command names, e.g. `echo`, exist *both* as Bash builtins *and* as external utilities (`/bin/echo`).

While **just `info`** (without arguments) *will* show you a ***list* of *external* utilities, typically under heading `Individual utilities`**, there are **problems**; depending on your system:

- The list may be *incomplete*, or spread across multiple locations.
- The documentation may not refer to the actual utilities installed on your system.

  - For instance, on OSX the `info` topics document the *GNU* core utilities, whereas OSX *mostly* comes with *BSD* utilities.
- If, however, your system is a Linux distro that *does* use the *GNU* utilities (which is the norm) and the `info` command is the one that came with `bash`, you may be fine.
- See below for commands that allow you to find all external utilities in your `$PATH`.
- An alternative way to get a *list* of external utilities is to consult **the set of POSIX-mandated utilities**; note that this list will only be a *subset* of the set of utilities installed on most modern platforms; similarly, the individual utility description will typically only describe the - standardized - *subset* of a given platform's version of that utility, because most utilities implement nonstandard *extension*:

  - Go to [Shell & Utilities: Detailed Toc](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/contents.html) and search for heading `Utilities` (as the full heading), which lists all *external utilities* a POSIX-compliant system must have.<sup>I couldn't find a direct link to a page listing all utilities by name.</sup>
  - POSIX also mandates the  *builtins* (built-in utilities) that a POSIX-compliant shell must implement (of which the Bash builtins are a *superset*):

    - [Built-in utilities](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap01.html#tag_17_06)
    - [*Special* built-in utilities](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/contents.html)

---

**Additional information:**

- To **see whether a given command is a *builtin***, use, e.g.:

```
 $ type read
 read is a shell builtin
```

- To **see *all* forms of a command**, use option `-a`, e.g.:

```
 $ type -a read
 read is a shell builtin
 read is /usr/bin/read
```

**How to find all (external) utilities in your `$PATH`:**

- The **following command will output a list of all executables in your `$PATH`** (this can be a long list); also note that the list will typically include utilities that were custom-installed; the list will contain ***full* paths, grouped by directory**:

  - The command looks for files that are executable by the `o` (*other*, rest of the word) security principal, which all preinstalled utilities should be; conceivably, there are additional utilities that have the permissions attribute only for the `u` and/or `g` principal.

```
printf '%s' "$PATH" | tr ':' '\n' | xargs -I {} find {} -maxdepth 1 -type f -perm -o=x
```

- If you want a **sorted list of mere executable *names***, use:

```
printf '%s' "$PATH" | tr ':' '\n' | xargs -I {} find {} -maxdepth 1 -type f -perm -o=x |
  awk -F/ '{ print $NF }' | sort -u
```

- The above lists only *unique* names; it is possible for distinct duplicates of executables with the same *filename* to exist in multiple directories in the `$PATH` (in which case the one whose directory comes *first* in `$PATH` "wins"); **to see a list of duplicates, prefixed with their occurrence count**, use:

```
printf '%s' "$PATH" | tr ':' '\n' | xargs -I {} find {} -maxdepth 1 -type f -perm -o=x |
  awk -F/ '{ print $NF }' | sort | uniq -c | grep -v ' *1'
```

- For any given name with duplicates you can use `which -a <name>` to see the full paths of all duplicates.

---

Finally, **tab completion** can be helpful in **discovering commands**:

- Type `man` and press the Tab key repeatedly to list / cycle through *all* command; specify a command prefix - e.g., `man dat` - to only list / cycle through the commands that *start* with that prefix (the exact behavior depends on your `readline` configuration).

  - By default this does *not* work with `info` (at least on the OSX and Ubuntu systems that I've tried this on from Bash).
- This also works when starting to type a command name to *invoke*.

  - However, that requires typing at least one letter, which limits the matches to commands whose name starts with that letter.
  - To discover *all* executables in a given folder, use:

    - `./<tab>` in the current folder.
    - `/usr/bin/<tab>`, for instance, in a specific folder.

Comment: This is great! Thank you for all of the details...at first glance this answer definitely provides the information I was looking for.

Comment: @BenWS: My pleasure; turns out that just `info` (no arguments) may give you what you want, but there are caveats - see my updated (and restructured) answer.